# Django inlineformset_factory how to properlu override the __init__ function

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

everyone!
I'm trying to pass a value to the **init** function and fill one of my field with data from another model.
I hardcoded the value to get the right data in my field.

I want to know, how to pass initial values into init function?
I found a lot of solutions but they doesn't work for me.

I've tried to pass primary key into initial func:

## forms.py

```py
class ObservationPartsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ObservationPartsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        primary = kwargs.get('pk')
        print('Get pk',primary) #Get pk None 
        instance = kwargs.get("instance")  
        meteostation = MeteoStation.objects.get(id=pk)
        if instance == None:
            meteoparam = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=meteostation.meteo_parametrs.select_related().filter(is_active=True),
                label='Метеопараметр',
            )
            self.fields['meteoparam'] = meteoparam
        else:
            value_selected = forms.ChoiceField(label='Значение для выбора')
            self.fields['value_selected'] = value_selected
            #print(instance)


    class Meta():
        model = ObservationParts
        fields = ('meteoparam',
                  'value_digit',
                  'value_selected',
                  'author_parts',
                  'who_updated')

ObservationEntireFormset = inlineformset_factory(ObservationEntire, ObservationParts,
                                                 form=ObservationPartsForm, extra=1,
                                                 )
```

## views.py

```py
class ObservePartsCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'dairy/test.html'
    model = ObservationParts
    #form_class = ObservationPartsForm
    success_message = 'Метеопараметры добавлены к наблюдению.'
    formset = None

    def get_form(self, form_class=None, **kwargs):
        pk_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        print(pk_)
        form = ObservationPartsForm(pk=pk_)
        return form

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        initial = super(ObservePartsCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['value_selected'] = ObserveDate.objects.all()
        return initial


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_ = kwargs.get("pk")
        observe_entire = ObservationEntire.objects.get(pk=pk_)
        self.formset = ObservationEntireFormset(instance=observe_entire)
        return super(ObservePartsCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ObservePartsCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = self.formset
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        observe_entire = ObservationEntire.objects.get(pk=pk_)
        self.formset = ObservationEntireFormset(request.POST, instance=observe_entire)
        if self.formset.is_valid():
            self.formset.save()
            return redirect('test', pk=observe_entire.id)
        else:
            return super(ObservePartsCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        pk_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        kwargs = super(ObservePartsCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['primary'] = pk_
        return kwargs
```

When I'm passing any values into **init** function I've got an error:

Exception Value:
'ObservationPartsForm' object has no attribute '**name**'

Traceback if i'm trying to pass value, like this

```py
ObservationEntireFormset = inlineformset_factory(ObservationEntire, ObservationParts,                                                form=ObservationPartsForm(pk=1), extra=1,)
```

Traceback:

```py
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/GreenTest/greenschool/greenApp/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
    path('', include('dairy.urls')),
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/GreenTest/greenschool/dairy/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dairy.views import *
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/GreenTest/greenschool/dairy/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dairy.forms import *
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/GreenTest/greenschool/dairy/forms.py", line 59, in <module>
    form=ObservationPartsForm(pk=1), extra=1,
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1077, in inlineformset_factory
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 878, in modelformset_factory
    validate_min=validate_min, validate_max=validate_max)
  File "/home/wess/Documents/Work/Green/VPS/env_green/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 441, in formset_factory
    return type(form.__name__ + 'FormSet', (formset,), attrs)
AttributeError: 'ObservationPartsForm' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback for this error please.

Comment: @CalebGoodman I added the full traceback, thank you fro help. It looks like I can't pass any parametrs.